# How to count consecutive repeats and create a column with the corrisponding ids of the counting?

Tags: r

I am performing some analysis in R but i need to count consecutive repeat and put togheter the IDs. 
I don´t want just to aggregate if there are similar ids, i would like to aggregate the specific ids when there are consecutive repeat. I have a file with these entries.

```
Probe Set ID    Call Codes  Chromosomal Position
SNP_A-2131660   BB           1156131
SNP_A-1967418   AB           2234251
SNP_A-1969580   BB           2329564
SNP_A-4263484   BB           2553624
SNP_A-1978185   AA           2936870
SNP_A-4264431   AA           2951834
SNP_A-1980898   BB           3095126
SNP_A-1983139   AA           3165267
SNP_A-4265735   AA           3302871
SNP_A-1995832   AA           3705226
SNP_A-1995893   AA           3720965
SNP_A-1997689   BB           3763164
SNP_A-1997709   AA           3763567
SNP_A-1997896   AA           3766240
SNP_A-1997922   AA           3766286
SNP_A-2000230   AA           4340877
SNP_A-2000332   AB           4343434
```

I woult like to count the consecutive values (i.e BB, AB, (BB, BB)) and if there are aggregate the other two columns.

I have tried in different way, but i have been able only to perfom the counts for consecutive reapeat with this code in R.

```
# I got the counts
dfAA <- as.data.frame(with(rle(myfile$Call.Codes), lengths[values == "AA"]))
# I got the counts and the counted values
dfAA_02<-as.data.frame(rev(unclass(rle(myfile$Call.Codes))))
```

I don´t know how to perform the second part.

That is what i would like to obtain at the end.

```
    Counts  Aggregation_probeset_ID Aggregation Chromosomal position
BB  1      SNP_A-2131660                        1156131   
AB  1      SNP_A-1967418                        2234251  
BB  2      SNP_A-1969580, SNP_A-4263484         2329564, 2553624  
AA  2      SNP_A-1978185, SNP_A-4264431         2936870, 2951834  
AA  4      SNP_A-1983139, SNP_A-4265735, SNP_A-1995832, SNP_A-1995893      3165267, 3302871, 3705226, 3720965
```

[My file with what i would like to obtain on the right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKeer.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data[, lag := shift(Call_Codes, 1L, fill = , type = "lag")]
data[, new_group := if_else(lag != Call_Codes, 1, 0, missing = 1)]
data[, new_group := cumsum(new_group)]
data[, .(counts = .N,
         Aggregation_probeset_ID = paste(Probe_Set_ID , collapse=","),
         Aggregation_Chromosomal_position = paste(Chromosomal_Position , collapse=","))
         , .(Call_Codes, new_group)][, -c('new_group')]
```

The results:

```
   Call_Codes counts                                 Aggregation_probeset_ID Aggregation_Chromosomal_position
1:         BB      1                                           SNP_A-2131660                          1156131
2:         AB      1                                           SNP_A-1967418                          2234251
3:         BB      2                             SNP_A-1969580,SNP_A-4263484                  2329564,2553624
4:         AA      2                             SNP_A-1978185,SNP_A-4264431                  2936870,2951834
5:         BB      1                                           SNP_A-1980898                          3095126
6:         AA      4 SNP_A-1983139,SNP_A-4265735,SNP_A-1995832,SNP_A-1995893  3165267,3302871,3705226,3720965
7:         BB      1                                           SNP_A-1997689                          3763164
8:         AA      4 SNP_A-1997709,SNP_A-1997896,SNP_A-1997922,SNP_A-2000230  3763567,3766240,3766286,4340877
9:         AB      1                                           SNP_A-2000332                          4343434
```

Comment: Hi Metariat, i thank you a lot. it is excatly what i needed. It worked perfectly. Could I ask you a little explanation of the functions you used in order to understand the code but better?